# Show Navigation on specific button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using **nav-link** for tabs need to go second tab directly after 1 tab submit

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">VIEW ENTITIES</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">CREATE ENTITY</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I tried

```
('#profile').show()
```

[image: UI of Tabs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly you mean you need to trigger the `tab2` when you click on `tab1` right?

Then use the Jquery Trigger:

```js
$('#profile-tab').trigger('click');
```

Please let me know if this helps

Comment: $('#home-tab').on('click', function(){  $('#profile-tab').trigger('click') })

Comment: you are most Welcome

Answer (score 2):

***HTML Nav Tabs Bootstrap 4***

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
            aria-selected="true">VIEW ENTITIES</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile"
            aria-selected="false">CREATE ENTITY</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact"
            aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Content tabs**

```
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <input class="btn btn-info nextTab" type="submit" >
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
            <input class="btn btn-info nextTab" type="submit" >
    </div>        
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
            <input class="btn btn-info nextTab" type="submit" >
    </div>
</div>
```

***Generic next step***

```
    <script>
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('.nextTab').on('click',function(){

                //Unidirectional -->

                var nextTAB = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;

                if ( nextTAB != undefined ) {
                    //Do some stuff and then.. change the tab.
                    jQuery('#'+nextTAB.id+'-tab').trigger('click');
                } 

            });
        });

  </script>
```